# New at Python//Dictionaries and lists

Tags: python

I have two different Codes and i want to know Why one of them dont work?
Thanks for ur help.

#1

```
fahrzeug1 = dict(marke = "VW", modell = "Golf", Baujahr=2012, preis= 2500)
fahrzeug2 = dict(marke="Porsche",modell="cayman", baujahr=2019, preis=21999)
fahrezeug3= dict(marke="BMW",modell="3er",baujahr=2014, preis=8000)

listefahrzeuge = [fahrzeug1,fahrzeug2,fahrezeug3]

max = eval(input("Geben sie bitte ihren höchst Preis an: "))

if fahrzeug1["preis"] <= max:
    print(fahrzeug1, "\n")
if fahrzeug2["preis"] <= max:
    print(fahrzeug2, "\n")
if fahrezeug3["preis"] <= max:
    print(fahrezeug3, "\n")
```

#2

```
fahrzeug1 = dict(marke = "VW", modell = "Golf", Baujahr=2012, preis= 2500)
fahrzeug2 = dict(marke="Porsche",modell="cayman", baujahr=2019, preis=21999)
fahrezeug3= dict(marke="BMW",modell="3er",baujahr=2014, preis=8000)

listefahrzeuge = [fahrzeug1,fahrzeug2,fahrezeug3]

max = eval(input("Geben sie bitte ihren höchst Preis an: "))

if listefahrzeuge[0][3] <= max:
    print(fahrzeug1, "\n")
if listefahrzeuge[1][3] <= max:
    print(fahrzeug2, "\n")
if listefahrzeuge[2][3] <= max:
    print(fahrezeug3, "\n")
```

Comment: Sry first time on stackoverflow

Comment: no worries; welcome -- first note is from a security perspective `eval` is scary -- people can type arbitrary code and eval will run it -- here you likely want `int`

Comment: I'd also avoid using `max` or `min` as variable names -- since they're python reserved words, using them then later trying something like `max([1,2,3])` will likely cause unintended behaviors

Comment: What error do you get when you run this code? It looks like it'd work to me -- I'm assuming it's an issue with the `eval` since the provided integer isn't a `code object` -- if you replace `eval` with `int` does it work as expected?

Comment: wait a min. Will start the code

Comment: Geben sie bitte ihren höchst Preis an: 9000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\PC\Desktop\Python\Python6.1 copy.py", line 7, in <module>
    if listefahrzeuge[0][3] <= max:
KeyError: 3

Comment: ahh, yes -- the object is a dictionary not a list replace `listefahrzeuge[0][3]` with `listefahrzeuge[0]['preis']`

Comment: ah okay thanks for ur help. helped me rly much.

Comment: Glad that helped -- I reposted as an answer so you can close it out. FWIW -- when you're having issues with code it's best to post the traceback in the question (it'll help us help you) cheers & welcome to the platform!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval` should be replaced with either an `int` or a `float` depending on what you're looking for.

Also with noting that `eval` will allow the user to input arbitrary code and execute that code -- this presents a security risk in a lot of cases, you **generally** should avoid using eval.

The other issue is listefahrzeuge is a list of dictionaries, not a list of lists so `listefahrzeuge[0][3]` needs to be replaced with `listefahrzeuge[0]['preis']`

For what it's worth you can replace this:

```
if fahrzeug1["preis"] <= user_input:
    print(fahrzeug1, "\n")
if fahrzeug2["preis"] <= user_input
    print(fahrzeug2, "\n")
if fahrezeug3["preis"] <= user_input:
    print(fahrezeug3, "\n")
```

with this:

```
for d in listefahrzeuge:
  if d['preis'] <= user_input:
    print(d)
```

with `user_input = int(input("Geben sie bitte ihren höchst Preis an: "))`